# Create an index on the same column but two different usage

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I want to create the below index on Ef Core using fluent aPI, but I didn't find any information to answer my this problem.

```
CREATE INDEX test_ix ON test_table ((column_x IS NOT NULL) DESC, column_x DESC)
```

I don't want to make filtered index like the below:

```
CREATE INDEX test_ix ON test_table (column_x DESC) WHERE column_x IS NOT NULL
```

It does not correspond my needs.

Comment: Doc : [EF Core - Filtered index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes?tabs=data-annotations#index-filter)

Comment: Unfortunately @vernou. I don't know how to create an index  like that on EF core. `CREATE INDEX test_ix ON test_table ((column_x IS NOT NULL) DESC, column_x DESC)`